# What are the blue gems for?

Tags: frogatto-and-friends

Every now and then a defeated enemy drops something that looks like a blue gem.  It's sparkly and really bouncy, so it can be hard to catch if you're on land.

[image: Blue Gem]

Grabbing one makes a little blue pulse come out of Frogatto, but other than that I haven't noticed any other side effects.  What do they do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured it out.

These gems replenish your *magic*, which is consumed by abilities other than the tongue.  (fire breath, for example).  Magic regenerates on its own over time, but it's *very slow*.

Magic is represented by the green bar in the upper-left corner of the screen, above your health.

[image: Magic Bar]

Comment: [It's _mana_, not _magic_](https://github.com/frogatto/frogatto/blob/66e53034c8e36e87ec90b00fd015b92558a52664/data/object_prototypes/base/player_controlled.cfg#L634-L651).